# Error in calling php file in html table data using Ajax and data.html

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, json

I have small project in which i have different news.I have to include this news_all.php file in table data in the dashboard.php file. I have predefined root structure in which i cannot use include('news.php) and i dont want to use it. So in this case how i can be able to call news.php file in this table data in dashboard.php file.I have used Ajax method.I am almost done but having small mistake in my code.Any help.Thanks. Here is my code:

dashboard.php

```
    <?php


    $page['register-news'] = array(
    1   => array( 'News','aktiv',$page['script'],'',''),

    $page['content'] .= '
    <table width="538" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" >
        <tr>
            <td id="news">
                <div>'.CreateRegister($page['register-news']).'</div>
                '.CreateMessage().'
                <div class="cont-liste-verlauf register">           


                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>';


    ?>
```

news_all.php

```
    <?php
    include 'constant/const_system.inc.php';
    include 'functions/ad_json.inc';
    include 'functions/ad_formulare.inc';
$page['doctype'] = true;
$param = array_merge($_GET, $_POST);

$return = array();
if($param['aktion'] == 'get-news')
{
    $page['register-news'] = array(
    1   => array( 'News','aktiv',$page['script'],'',''),
);
    $html = 
    '<table width="538" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
    <tr>
    <td>

    <a href="news.php?id=" class="TrackNews" id="01">
    <div class="welcome-rahmen lng toggleNews" id="news_269_kurz">
    <p class="welcome-breadcrump">Montag, 19.05.2014</p>
    <p class="welcome-subheadline">Teilnahme von MAN Top Used an der Samoter 2014</p>
    <div class="newsText">
    <p class="welcome-text"><img src="http://intern.autodo.de/admin/news/man-it.jpg" width="165" class="text_fixed" border="0"></p>
    <p class="welcome-text">Die 29. Internationale Erd- und Bautechnik-Ausstellung Samoter fand zwischen dem 8. und 11. Mai in Verona statt und zog rund 100.000 Besucher an. Samoter ist die wichtigste italienische Messe ihrer Art, die den Themen Erdbewegung, Hochbau und Baumaschinen gewidmet ist. Zugleich ist diese Veranstaltung damit auch f? europ?chen Markt bedeutsam.</p>
    </div>
    </div>
    </a>

    <a href="news.php?id=" class="TrackNews" id="02">
    <div class="welcome-rahmen lng toggleNews" id="news_264_kurz">
    <p class="welcome-breadcrump">Freitag, 24.01.2014</p>
    <p class="welcome-subheadline">Kaufvertrag: neue Porsche-Vorlage zum Drucken!</p>
    <div class="newsText">
    <img src="http://intern.autodo.de/admin/news/porsche-kaufvertrag.jpg" border="0" align="right" class="img_fixed" width=60><p class="welcome-text">Ihr AMO Druckcenter bietet Ihnen ab sofort die M?chkeit, Kaufvertr? im Porsche-Design zu nutzen.</p>
    <p class="page-breadcrump">AutoDo!-Team</p>
    </div>
    </div>
    </a>
    </td>
    </tr>
    </table>';
    $return = array(
            'status' => 1,
            'html'  => $html
        );

        echo(json_encode($return)) ;
    }
    ?>
```

ajax.js

```
$.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "news_all.php",
      dataType : 'json',
      cache: false,
      data: {'aktion' : 'get-news'},
      success: function(data){
      $('#news').html(data.html);
      }
    });
```

Here is the image of output in firebug

[image]

Comment: yes exactly i knw the structure and i have share part of my code as well

Comment: From what I understand, your ajax-call loads something else than the json you echo out. I notice you include some files at the top of all_news.php. Does anyone of these contain anything that could be outputted?

Comment: no it does not contain the output of all_news.php file

Comment: What I'm asking is: does const_system.inc.php, ad_json.inc or ad_formulare.inc contain anything that would be outputted? Not if it contains the output of all_news.php

Comment: hey i think you are right my only mistake was i did not format my code well.I have formatted my code now properly and its working fine .Thank you.:)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer of my code:

```
<?php

include 'constant/const_system.inc.php';
include 'functions/ad_json.inc';
include 'functions/ad_formulare.inc';

$page['doctype'] = true;
$param = array_merge($_GET, $_POST);

$return = array();
if($param['aktion'] == 'get-news')
{
    $page['register-news'] = array(
    1   => array( 'News','aktiv',$page['script'],'',''),
);

$html =     
'
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tr>
<td class="page-head">
<img src="/admin/images/background/admin_head_bar_de.gif" border="0" alt="Fahrzeuge einfach effizient verwalten."><br>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="welcome-page-hint">

<table width="538" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
<tr>
<td>

<a href="news.php?id=" class="TrackNews" id="01">
<div class="welcome-rahmen lng toggleNews" id="news_269_kurz">
<p class="welcome-breadcrump">Montag, 19.05.2014</p>
<p class="welcome-subheadline">Teilnahme von MAN Top Used an der Samoter 2014</p>
<div class="newsText">
<p class="welcome-text"><img src="http://intern.autodo.de/admin/news/man-it.jpg" width="165" class="text_fixed" border="0"></p>
<p class="welcome-text">Die 29. Internationale Erd- und Bautechnik-Ausstellung Samoter fand zwischen dem 8. und 11. Mai in Verona statt und zog rund 100.000 Besucher an. Samoter ist die wichtigste italienische Messe ihrer Art, die den Themen Erdbewegung, Hochbau und Baumaschinen gewidmet ist. Zugleich ist diese Veranstaltung damit auch f? europ?chen Markt bedeutsam.</p>
</div>
</div>
</a>

<a href="news.php?id=" class="TrackNews" id="02">
<div class="welcome-rahmen lng toggleNews" id="news_264_kurz">
<p class="welcome-breadcrump">Freitag, 24.01.2014</p>
<p class="welcome-subheadline">Kaufvertrag: neue Porsche-Vorlage zum Drucken!</p>
<div class="newsText">
<img src="http://intern.autodo.de/admin/news/porsche-kaufvertrag.jpg" border="0" align="right" class="img_fixed" width=60><p class="welcome-text">Ihr AMO Druckcenter bietet Ihnen ab sofort die M?chkeit, Kaufvertr? im Porsche-Design zu nutzen.</p>
<p class="page-breadcrump">AutoDo!-Team</p>
</div>
</div>
</a>

<a href="news.php?id=" class="TrackNews" id="03">
<div class="welcome-rahmen lng toggleNews" id="news_265_kurz">
<p class="welcome-breadcrump">Mittwoch, 15.01.2014</p>
<p class="welcome-subheadline">AutoDo! Update: Die Eigenschaft -Unfallfahrzeug- wurde im AMO erweitert!</p>
<div class="newsText">
<p class="welcome-text">Ab sofort k?n Sie Fahrzeuge nach folgenden Kriterien kennzeichnen:</p>
<p class="highlight"><b>? Unfallfahrzeug<br>
? Unfallfrei<br>
? Keine Angabe</b></p>
<p class="page-breadcrump">AutoDo!-Team</p>
</div>
</div>
</a>

<a href="news.php?id=" class="TrackNews" id="04">
<div class="welcome-rahmen krz toggleNews" id="news_262_kurz">
<p class="welcome-breadcrump">Dezember 2013</p>
<p class="welcome-subheadline">NUR OFFLINE!:<br>Machen Sie Ihre Preise fit f? Zukunft:<br>attraktive Preisregulierung mit dem neuen Preismanagement!</p>
<div class="newsText" style="display:none;">
<p class="welcome-text">Entscheiden Sie sich jetzt f? Erweiterungsmodul <b>AMO</b><i>profi!</i> und sichern Sie sich neben umfangreichen Auswertungsm?chkeiten und einem automatischen B?ncheck das brandneue Preismanagement mit folgenden Vorteilen:</p>
<p class="page-breadcrump">AutoDo!-Team</p>
</div>
</div>
</a>

<a href="news.php?id=" class="TrackNews" id="05">
<div class="welcome-rahmen krz toggleNews" id="news_261_kurz">
<p class="welcome-breadcrump">Montag, 02.12.2013</p>
<p class="welcome-subheadline">Zeitsparend und einfach: Automatischer Preisschildversand mit AMO<i>profi!</i></p>
<div class="newsText" style="display:none;">
<img src="/admin/news/preisschild.jpg" border="0" align="right" width="110"><p class="welcome-text">Ab sofort k?n Sie bei Preis?erungen von Fahrzeugen <b>automatisch aktuelle Preisschilder</b> generieren und diese <b>per E-Mail</b> an die gew?en Empf?er weiterleiten! Diese Funktion ist jetzt im Erweiterungsmodul <b>AMO</b><i>profi!</i> erh?lich.</p>
<p class="page-breadcrump">AutoDo!-Team</p>
</div>
</div>
</a>

<a href="news.php?id=" class="TrackNews" id="06">
<div class="welcome-rahmen krz toggleNews" id="news_260_kurz">
<p class="welcome-breadcrump">Montag, 02.12.2013</p>
<p class="welcome-subheadline">Achtung: Ge?erte Modellzuordnung von Mazda und Ford Focus!</p>
<div class="newsText" style="display:none;">
<img src="/admin/news/ford-mazda.gif" border="0" align="right" width="100"><p class="welcome-text">Laut einer aktuellen Information durch <b>mobile.de</b> ist ab dem <b>02.12.2013</b> auf Wunsch der Hersteller Mazda und Ford die Eingabe folgender Modelle per Schnittstelle nicht mehr m?ch: <b>Mazda2, Mazda3, Mazda5, Mazda6 sowie Ford Focus C-Max!</b></p>
<p class="page-breadcrump">AutoDo!-Team</p>
</div>
</div>
</a>

<a href="news.php?id=" class="TrackNews" id="07">
<div class="welcome-rahmen krz toggleNews" id="news_259_kurz">
<p class="welcome-breadcrump">Mittwoch, 20.11.2013</p>
<p class="welcome-subheadline">AutoDo! Update:<br>Exportieren Sie Ihre Fahrzeugbilder zu mercedes-benz.de!</p>
<div class="newsText" style="display:none;"><p class="welcome-text"><img src="/admin/news/mb-boerse.jpg" border="0" width="70" class="img11_fixed">
<p class="welcome-text"></a>Ab sofort k?n Ihre Fahrzeugbilder direkt aus AutoDo! zur Gebrauchtfahrzeugsuche unter <a href="http://www.mercedes-benz.de">www.mercedes-benz.de</a> exportiert werden.</p>

<p class="page-breadcrump">AutoDo!-Team</p>
</div>
</div>
</a>

<a href="news.php?id=" class="TrackNews" id="11">
<div class="welcome-rahmen krz toggleNews" id="news_258_kurz">
<p class="welcome-breadcrump">Mittwoch, 20.11.2013</p>
<p class="welcome-subheadline">Automatische E-Mail-Benachrichtigung ?eue Fahrzeuge im System!</p>
<div class="newsText" style="display:none;">
<p class="welcome-text"><img src="/admin/news/neueingetroffen.jpg" border="0" align="right" width="70"></a>Auf Wunsch informiert Sie Ihr AMO ab sofort t?ich per E-Mail ?eu in das System eingespielte Fahrzeuge. Somit k?n Sie diese noch schneller und gezielter vermarkten!</p>
<p class="page-breadcrump">AutoDo!-Team</p>
</div>
</div>
</a>

<a href="news.php?id=" class="TrackNews" id="12">
<div class="welcome-rahmen krz toggleNews" id="news_255_kurz">
<p class="welcome-breadcrump">Dienstag, 01.10.2013</p>
<p class="welcome-subheadline">ACHTUNG: Wichtige Info zum Fahrzeugexport in die Neuwagenb? von mobile.de!</p>
<div class="newsText" style="display:none;">
<p class="welcome-text"><a href="http://suchen.mobile.de/neu/auto/" target="_blank"><img src="/admin/news/mobile-nw.jpg" border="0" align="right" width="50"></a>Es ist soweit: die mobile.de Neuwagenwelt ist online. Damit ein Fahrzeug hier angezeigt werden kann, m?folgende Kriterien beachtet werden:</p>
<p class="welcome-text" style="padding:0 0 0 20px;"><b>· </b> Ihr Account muss einmalig durch den mobile.de Support <br>
  <b>f? Neuwagenwelt frei geschaltet werden</b>.*<br>
<b>· </b> Es werden <b>ausschlie?ich Lagerfahrzeuge</b> angezeigt.<br>
</p>
</div>
</div>
</a>

<a href="news.php?id=" class="TrackNews" id="10">
<div class="welcome-rahmen krz toggleNews" id="news_254_kurz">
<p class="welcome-breadcrump">Donnerstag, 19.09.2013</p>
<p class="welcome-subheadline">Gelangensbest?gung: jetzt als Vorlage in Ihrem AMO Druckcenter!</p>
<div class="newsText" style="display:none;">
    <p class="welcome-text"><img src="http://intern.autodo.de/admin/news/gelangens-de.gif" border="0" width="210" align="right" class="img12_fixed"></p>
<p class="welcome-text">Ab dem <b>01.10.2013</b> wird f?Verk?e im Abholfalle die Erstellung einer entsprechenden <b>Gelangensbest?gung</b> gefordert, um sicherzustellen, dass die Ware tats?lich im anderen EU-Mitgliedsstaat angekommen ist.</p>
<p class="page-breadcrump">AutoDo!-Team</p>
</div>
</div>
</a>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
<p class="page-fusszeile">Copyright 2001-2014 Marc van Eupen &middot; AutoDo GmbH &middot; Burgdorf, Deutschland<br>Alle Rechte vorbehalten.</p>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="d-abstand-shaddow"><img src="/autodo/img/blank.gif" width="1" height="50" alt=""></td>
</tr>
</table>';
$return = array(
        'status' => 1,
        'html'  => $html
    );

    echo(json_encode($return)) ;
}
?>
```